# Get the selected html text from div and save the text as string jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have a div in which I display the data read from text file now i want to get the selected text in save into a variable.

**MyCode:**

```
@section scripts
{

    <script>

        myHub = $.connection.myHub;
        $.connection.hub.start()
            .done(function() {

                @*console.log("Connected");
                console.log(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.filePath)));
                myHub.server.announce(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.filePath)));*@
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert("It Fail");
            });

        jQuery.get(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.filePath)),
            function(txt) {
                $("#LoadText").text(txt);
            });



        //if (!window.x) {
        //    x = {};
        //}
        //x.Selector = {};
        //x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
        //    var t = '';
        //    if (window.getSelection) {
        //        t = window.getSelection();
        //    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        //        t = document.getSelection();
        //    } else if (document.selection) {
        //        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
        //    }
        //    return t;
        //}

        //$(function() {
        //    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
        //        var mytext = x.Selector.getSelected();
        //        console.log(mytext.html);
        //    });
        //});




    </script>
}
```

**I tried the comment code and it is not working because it returns the
object but i want a string value**

Comment: Tell us more in order to help you. Maybe try to provide the code in jsfiddle?